# Error message 'No line here to end' when delete a chunk of code

Tags: posters

These are the syntex that construct a box in a poster template:

```
\headerbox{Results}{name=model, span=3,column=0, below=SNP}{ \large \sf
% The result section is split up in two pieces 
% PART 1 (left)
\begin{minipage}{0.49\linewidth}
    % add a description
    \begin{description} 
        % Set condensed list
        \compresslist 
        % set font size
        \large
        \item[{\color{BL} criterion A}] text ...\\
    \end{description}
    % align left
    \begin{flushleft} 
    {
    \footnotesize 
    \begin{tabular}{llcc} 
    \hline
    criterion& method & distribution $p$ & type I (w.r.t. $\alpha$) \\
    \hline
    A   & ++    & uniform & nominal\\
    B   & ++    & uniform & more conservative \\
    C   & --    & uniform & nominal \\
    D   & --    & uniform & slightly more liberal \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular} 
    }
    \vspace{2cm}\\
    %include figure
    \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth, page=3]{f4.pdf}
    \end{flushleft}
    \begin{description}
        \item[{\color{BL} criterion B}] ...
    \end{description}
    \vfill
\end{minipage}  
% PART 2 (right)    
\begin{minipage}{0.49\linewidth}
    \begin{description}
        % Set condensed list
        \compresslist 
        % set font size
        \large
        \item[{\color{BL} Criterion C }] ...
        \item[{\color{BL} Criterion D }] ...
    \end{description}
    \begin{flushleft}
    {
    \footnotesize 
    \begin{tabular}{llcc} 
    \hline
    measure     & parameter     & $t$ value     & $p$ value  \\
    \hline
    1   & $\beta_0$     & $1.28$    &   $<0.01$ \\
    2   & $\beta_0$     & $1.28$    &   $<0.01$ \\
    3   & $\beta_0$     & $1.28$    &   $<0.01$ \\
    4   & $\beta_0$     & $1.28$    &   $<0.01$ \\
    5   & $\beta_0$     & $1.28$    &   $<0.01$ \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular} 
    }
    \vspace{2cm} \\
    %include figure
    \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth, page=3]{f4.pdf}
    \end{flushleft}
    \vfill
\end{minipage}          
}
```

[image: box]

The structure that I want in this box is:
[image: want]

So I need to delete the syntax that construct a tabular, then I delete this part:

```
\begin{flushleft} 
        {
        \footnotesize 
        \begin{tabular}{llcc} 
        \hline
        criterion& method & distribution $p$ & type I (w.r.t. $\alpha$) \\
        \hline
        A   & ++    & uniform & nominal\\
        B   & ++    & uniform & more conservative \\
        C   & --    & uniform & nominal \\
        D   & --    & uniform & slightly more liberal \\
        \hline
        \end{tabular} 
        }
        \vspace{2cm}\\
        %include figure
        \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth, page=3]{f4.pdf}
        \end{flushleft}
        \begin{description}
            \item[{\color{BL} criterion B}] ...
        \end{description}
        \vfill
```

My **Question** is:
The error occured is `No line here to end`. i found that the problem is not because I didn't delete this chunk of code completely. I tried some solutions that I found online, like, which is add `\leavevmode \\`. I also check the solution in the current web, but they don't work. Could anyone offer any else solution? Thank you.

Comment: just delete all the `\\ ` that are not ending table rows. They are all wrong (although not all of them generate an error) But please always make an example that people can run to see the issue, not just a fragment.

Comment: it is hard to be definite with no usable example but replacing `\vspace{2cm} \\ ` by a blank line followed by `\vspace{2cm}` will probably fix the error.